# SQL - "linking" 2 Primary Keys to 2 different tables?

Tags: sql

I have these 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(ORDER_NUM CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_NUM) REFERENCES CUSTOMER,
ORDER_DATE DATE,
CUSTOMER_NUM CHAR(3) );

CREATE TABLE PART
(PART_NUM CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRIPTION CHAR(15),
ON_HAND DECIMAL(4,0) CHECK (ON_HAND >= 0),
CLASS CHAR(2),
WAREHOUSE CHAR(1),
PRICE DECIMAL(6,2) );

CREATE TABLE ORDER_LINE
(ORDER_NUM CHAR(5),
PART_NUM CHAR(4),
NUM_ORDERED DECIMAL(3,0) CHECK (NUM_ORDERED >= 0),
QUOTED_PRICE DECIMAL(6,2),
PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUM, PART_NUM));
```

As you can see, ORDER_LINE contains 2 Primary Keys - ORDER_NUM and PART_NUM, which should be linked to the other tables.

What would be the best way to link ORDER_NUM to the ORDER_NUM that's in the ORDERS table, and PART_NUM to PART_NUM that's in the PART table?

Would it just be adding:

```
PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUM, PART_NUM),
FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NUM) REFERENCES ORDERS,
FOREIGN KEY (PART_NUM) REFERENCES PART);
```

to that last table?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but: you most certainly do **not** want `CHAR` for e.g. the `decscription` column. In general, forget about `char` you almost always want `varchar` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, ORDER_LINE contains 2 Primary Keys - ORDER_NUM and
>   PART_NUM, which should be linked to the other tables.

ORDER_LINE contains *one* primary key; that primary key consists of two columns.

Yes, you can just add this to ORDER_LINE.

```
PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUM, PART_NUM),
FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NUM) REFERENCES ORDERS,
FOREIGN KEY (PART_NUM) REFERENCES PART);
```